# Sendgrid links in email produce Your connection is not private error in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid

Rails 5.2
SendGrid
Heroku App

I have a link in an email to view a report.
The links work perfectly in development.

However, when SendGrid sends the emails in production and I click on the link in the email I get the following error in the browser:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from myapp.heroku.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

In my production config I have the following:

```
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://provenwordapp.heroku.com' }
```

From other SO users the above worked for them. However, it's not working for me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: _“when SendGrid sends the emails in production I get the following error in the browser”_ - you mean when viewing the email already, or at the point when you try to view that specific report URL? `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` doesn’t sound like it had much to do with the latter.

Comment: updated my question to clarify. When I click the specific report url.

Comment: And how is this link generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I did not use the correct URL for my app on Heroku.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://provenword.herokuapp.com' }
```

I had written heroku.com instead of herokuapp.com

Thanks to everyone for their assistance.

Comment: Where do I set the ``config`` like you guys are doing?

Comment: That is in the environment files e.g. `config/environments/production.rb`

Answer (score 19):

Have you [enabled SSL Click Tracking](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Track/Clicks/clicktracking_ssl.html) on your SendGrid account?

That error is generally because you're moving from an HTTPS > HTTP connection, or vice versa. If you have SendGrid's Click Tracking enabled, but don't have SSL enabled, their tracked links will be `http://`, even though your base link is `https://`.

Comment: The hoops required to get SSL working alone caused me to just turn off Click Tracking. Reasoning being: if you are sending a link of your own, it likely goes through analytics anyway, so it's not actually "untracked" but it no longer has that spammy vibe either.

Comment: @digitalextremist you are so right. I did just that. I think it is easier to track the clicks on my own than through #SendGrid